# .Net Core Web Api using DateTime as a controller parameter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, momentjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple API Controller that takes two dates and returns entities for the given range.

```
public List<Dto.Event> GetAll(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
   return EventService.GetAll(start, end);
}
```

On the client side I'm using FullCalendar.IO (which uses Moment.JS) but it seems like not matter how I parse or format the start and end date, the API controller never picks them up and it's *start* and *end* params are always set to '{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}'

Ideally I'd like to simply pass them in in the 'YYYY-DD-MM' format.

Client side code:

```
 function fetchCalendarEvents(start, end, timezone, callback) {

                $http({
                    url: '/api/events/',
                    method: "GET",
                    params: {
                        start: moment(start).format('YYYY-DD-MM'),
                        end: moment(end).format('YYYY-DD-MM')
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.events = response.data;
                })
}
```

Comment: Check it once with plain data which is given by fullCalender selected value. You should check your `moment(start)` value as well to make sure, it's correctly making object

Comment: moment().format('YYYY-DD-MM') works fine. Can you try to console.log(start) or console.log(end). You can use moment(new Date(start)) if you get  date variable as a valid string